# How to get Value of All textbox of Div?

Tags: jquery

I have a div Container, and I am creating a dynamic textbox control when an Add button is clicked

```
<div id="Container">
    <input type="Submit" id="AddTextBox" value="Add">
    <!-- Here are my dynamic textboxes -->
    <input type="text" value='' class="dynamic">
    <input type="text" value='' class="dynamic">
    <input type="text" value='' class="dynamic">
</div>

<input type="create" id="create" onclick="GetValue();" value="create">
```

I want to get the value of all textbox controls, eg:

```
Function GetValue()
{
    var COntain=TextBoxValue+"$"+Textbox2Value+"$"; // so on
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function GetValue(){
    var Contain = "";
    $("#Container :text").each(function(){
        Contain += $(this).val() + "$";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you $ separated concatenated value of all text boxes with div having id = "Container"

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/3pM2P/2/)**

```
str = "";
$('#Container input[type=text]').each(function (){
  str+=$(this).val() + "$";
});

//To remove the extra $ at end  
if(str != "")  
    str = str.substring(0,str.length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var completetext ='';
$('.dynamic').each(function() {
    completetext = completetext + ', ' +$(this).val();
});
```

output will be stored in the variable `completetext`